# How to power a Raspberry Pi 4 through usb c or gpio pins?

Tags: gpio, power-supply, voltage, activity-led

Hello everyone I am running into some kind of problem. I want to power my Pi 4B+ through the GPIO pins via a buck converter but it just wont work.
I used the LM2596 non adj 5V buck. In its typical application form. [image: dsf]

And I also bought the LM2596 adj and set it with the potmeter that comes with it.
It has a small voltage riple but stays within the 5% of 5V [tolerance](https://github.com/raspberrypi/hats/blob/master/designguide.md#back-powering-the-pi-via-the-gpio-header). And the third thing I tried was to supply it with my bench power supply. I tried al 3 cases with GPIO powering and via a stripped usb c cable but none of them work.

All tries end up with the red led staying on for a couple of seconds while the green led flashes but after that the red led dies.

My bench power supply can supply 4A at 5V and I even tried 5.1V as I read that the RPI adapter supplies that. Picture beneath shows PI 4B+ [schematic](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi4/raspberry-pi-4-reduced-schematics.pdf).

[image]

I also tried a 3S High discharge battery but that didnt solve it. Picture beneath shows setup.
[image]

I also measured the voltage while its been connected to the Pi. As you can see Vavg is 5.05V, Vmax 5.22V and Vmin 4.85V
[image]

Comment: Post a photo of your connections to the Pi. What diameter wire? Bench power supplies can't always react quickly enough for a Pi's power requirement. Have you tried leaving your power supply on then making a live connection to the Pi?

Comment: I have tried a battery instead of the bench power supplies it should provide quickly enough power to the pi. And I did try leaving the power supply on and making a live connection. I will add a picture of the current wiring with 3S battery. Diameter wiring is 1mm.

Comment: Can I see some twisted wire connections there - that is unlikely to work well - solder any connections. If connecting to GPIO use 2x 5V and 2x Gnd soldered to thicker wires.

Comment: Those are twisted and then soldered, but are the green and white cable from the usb c cable necessary I dont think so.

Comment: Most of your question is irrelevant as you appear to be using some (unspecified) converter. Many of these are low quality and if the PWR LED does not light it is obviously inadequate. You have not posted any voltage etc measurements.

Comment: I specified the converter in my question. These are indeed low quality but it has already been done: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=266296&p=1617905#p1617905 . The red light will turn on for a couple of seconds and I will add some measurements.